# How to use shell script to add a package into package.json?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to use a script to add a package into the `package.json` (without using npm install)?

This command give me the package version.

```
npm info grunt version
```

and this command write to the package.json:

```
sed -i '$s/}/,\n"dependencies":{ "grunt": "^........." } }/' package.json
```

I try to use pipe and $1 but it not working.

```
npm info grunt version | sed -i '$s/}/,\n"dependencies":{ "grunt": "^$1" } }/' package.json
```

Any idea what can be the solution?

Comment: Do you know `jq`?

Comment: no. but can I do it without install other tools? just what linux/windows have. because it should run on windows too. (cmder/bash)

Comment: Really, you want `jq`.